# Confusion regarding antenna element to element isolation in an array consisting of say 2 antennas

Tags: antenna

suppose one has an array of 2 isotropic  antennas used for spatial diversity , which means that they need to be as uncorrelated as possible, how does the coupling or isolation between them affect the diversity performance? so suppose the signal needs and SNR of 20 dB to be detected and the isolation is only 15 dB, how would this work?